# Why is my object empty after I filled it with data?

Tags: angular

This `user[]` object is used to hold data from a http request. In my html file it seems to be filled but in my component.ts its always empty!

```
public user = [];
ngOnInit() {
this.Jwt.getUserData().subscribe(
  data => this.user = data,
);
console.log(this.user)
console.log(this.user[0].name)
}
```

When I console it is empty.

Comment: Your HTML will detect any changes in values of component properties.. so it will update itself, under `ts` console.log() will run before the subscription finishes.. so its empty..

Comment: Thats coz `getUserData()` completes later in time, while the subsequent lines of console.log get executed before the response. Put `console.log(this.user)` inside the `subscribe` you should get the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so your issue is that your console logging users before users has actually been recieved, whats happening is that you call `getUserData` and then straight away you are console logging `this.user` even though the `console.log` is after the call, you still have to wait until you get your data to `console.log` it. So if you change your code to look like this..

```
public user = [];
 ngOnInit() {
  this.Jwt.getUserData().subscribe(data => {
    this.user = data
    console.log(this.user)
    console.log(this.user[0].name)
 });
}
```

you will get the desired result.

Comment: Great, thanks. But still I have an Issues. this.user[0].type is now working. Cannot read property of undefined

Comment: can you update your question with your latest code? Where do you call `this.user[0].type`

Comment: Just like your answer

Comment: I don't have `this.user[0].type` in my answer, is it written inside the getUserData function?

Comment: Its same as this.user[0].name, my mistake

Comment: I mean this.user[0].name still is not working, but yes I will mark it as answer